# Convert a time in milliseconds to local date string

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I am trying to convert a TimeStamp in milliseconds to a local date time. But this is weird.

The date is increased by 1 day. I don't know how stupid may I sound, but I would really be happy to have someone throw light on this.

**CODE:**

```
public static DateTime ConvertToLocalDate(string timeInMilliseconds){
     double timeInTicks = double.Parse(timeInMilliseconds);
     TimeSpan dateTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeInTicks);
     DateTime dateAfterEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1) + dateTimeSpan;
     DateTime dateInLocalTimeFormat = dateAfterEpoch.ToLocalTime();
     return dateInLocalTimeFormat;
}
```

For example, if I pass:
`1579631400000` which is equivalent to: `2020-01-21T18:30:00`
it returns: `1/22/2020 12:00:00 AM`

What is wrong?

Comment: In case you weren't aware... [`DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimemilliseconds?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Timezone, presumably.

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Wh0IdN. I suspect your local timezone is +5.30? India, perhaps?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand how to fix my code

Comment: What you are getting is the time in "your" timezone. Convert that to UTC then you will get it. `ConvertToLocalDate("1579631400000").ToUniversalTime()`

Comment: Firstly, can you confirm what your local timezone is?

Comment: OK, so `2020-01-21T18:30:00` in UTC is the same time as `1/22/2020 12:00:00 AM` in your local timezone (which is 5 and a half hours ahead of UTC). Do you want the final result to be in UTC (in which case remove the call to `ToLocalTime()`), or in your local timezone (in which case it's working as expected)?

Comment: @canton7 Yes it is

Comment: [See here](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html?iso=20200121T183000&p1=136&p2=176)

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I got confused because I didn't know how was the date in database stored and how I must display it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your ConvertToLocalDate function returns the date and time to your local time zone. You need to convert it to UTC to get the expected date and time.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ConvertToLocalDate("1579631400000").ToUniversalTime());

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static DateTime ConvertToLocalDate(string timeInMilliseconds)
        {
            double timeInTicks = double.Parse(timeInMilliseconds);
            TimeSpan dateTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeInTicks);
            DateTime dateAfterEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1) + dateTimeSpan;
            DateTime dateInLocalTimeFormat = dateAfterEpoch.ToLocalTime();
            return dateInLocalTimeFormat;
        }
    }
```

Or simply do not use ToLocalTime() inside your `ConvertToLocalDate` (if this is the case your function should not be named as Convert**ToLocalDate**)

Comment: Avoiding `ToLocalTime()` (and explicitly creating `dateAfterEpoch` as `UTC`) would be far preferable: remember that some datetimes aren't round-trippable (think of transitions to/from daylight savings), meaning that this code will fail in some edge cases

Answer (score 0):

Do nor use ToLocalTime().rest will work fine